# Как ограничить количество переданных неподтвержденных пакетов в TCP/IP?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, протоколы

> Всем известно, что при передаче потока TCP/IP он разбивается на
>   фрагменты которые могут передаваться по сети в отличном от исходного
>   порядке. Для систем с малым приемным буффером это может иметь
>   фатальные последствия, т.е. собрать поток становится невозможно.
>
> Возможно ли ограничить количество переданных неподтвержденных пакетов
>   до одного? И если возможно, то как?

Comment: это называется tcp window

Comment: @etki Я думаю, вы мне простите некоторое невежество в терминологии. Я хотел точнее передать смысл вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 2048  2048  2048
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 2048  2048  2048
```

в /etc/sysctl.conf

Note:

1. Так как вы не указали конкретную OS, я подразумеваю, что подойдёт решение для любой на выбор отвечающего.
2. Быстродействию сети после этого удивляться не сто́ит :)

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно я недостаточно точно задал вопрос. Речь идет не о настройке размера буфферов на отдельно взятой машине. Как сообщить клиенту сервера TCP/IP, что буффер приема крошечный?

Comment: Хорошо что это возможно, придется мне разбираться глубже и самому читать стандарты. Мне это нужно для микроконтроллера.

Comment: Не извиняйтесь, я вас правильно понял. Быстродействие не имеет особого значения, важна корректность и надежность.

Comment: О, вы самостоятельно себе делаете TCP-стек... Тогда, скорее всего, скоро я вам смогу задавать вопросы :) Касательно изменения размера окна - RFC 1323. Касательно управления потоком в целом... Тут вряд ли что-то могу посоветовать по собственному опыту, потому что не имел такового. Но, может быть, почитать что-нибудь по TCP congestion control (ключевые слова - "TCP reno", "TCP vegas", "TCP BIC" и посмотреть, как они сделаны в линуксовом ядре.

Comment: Во: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control

Comment: Нет, пока стек я не разрабатываю и не дорабатываю, а пытаюсь решить одну проблему. Выбрать недорогой контроллер Ethernet, для микроконтроллера способный устойчиво работать, и позволяющий исправить ошибки.

Comment: IP175?
Ethernet сам по себе не позволяет исправлять ошибки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81849/discussion-between--and-alexander-prokoshev).